# Java ConcurrentSkipListSet inconsistent with documentation

Tags: java, groovy, java.util.concurrent

Problem:
The documentation for contains and add for ConcurrentSkipListSet(csls) state the following:

public boolean add(E e)
Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that e.equals(e2). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

public boolean contains(Object o)
Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that o.equals(e).

But I dont see this behavior. The below code (unit test) exposes the discrepency.

```
@Test
public void testComparison() throws Exception {
    ObjectKey key = new ObjectKey("a", "b")
    MetricTimeDataContext entry1 = new MetricTimeDataContext(1l, "Count", 10, 0, key)
    MetricTimeDataContext entry2 = new MetricTimeDataContext(1l, "Count", 10, null, key)
    Assert.assertEquals(1, entry1 <=> entry2) // the compare shows entry1 > entry2
    Assert.assertNotEquals(entry1, entry2)    // entry != entry2
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, entry2.equals(entry1))  // EDIT: Added this since documentation states it is performing this test. this passes..
    Assert.assertNotEquals(entry1.hashCode(), entry2.hashCode())  // hashcodes are diff

    // this block shows correct functionality of ConcurrentHashMap
    def final Map<MetricTimeDataContext, Boolean> store = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
    store.put(entry1, Boolean.TRUE)
    Assert.assertFalse(store.containsKey(entry2)) // correct! since entry1 != entry2
    store.put(entry2, Boolean.TRUE)
    Assert.assertEquals(2, store.size())  // correct! 2 items added.

    // this block shows INcorrect functionality of ConcurrentSkipListSet
    def final Set<MetricTimeDataContext> dataStore = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>()
    Assert.assertTrue(dataStore.add(entry1))
    Assert.assertFalse(dataStore.contains(entry2)) // <--- this line fails unit test. why ???
    Assert.assertTrue(dataStore.add(entry2))  // <-- this line also fails if above line is absent

}
```

Am I missing something obvious ? The above entries(entry1,entry2) are clearly not equal but yet I cannot add them both the csls. what gives?

I need to use a Concurrent data structure since this code will be used in a distributed env (akka). Also MetricTimeDataContext implements comparable as illustrated in the unit test above and has appropriate equals and hashcode implementations.

thanks.

UPDATE: [SOLVED]
So Thanks to prodding by @mbs and @JasonC I added 2 more tests at the very top:

Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, entry2.equals(entry1))  // this passes (equality is fine)
Assert.assertEquals(-1, entry2 <=> entry1) // this returns 0 instead of -1 (comp is broken)

So my comparison algorithm is incorrect. .

Thanks again.

Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

Groovy:

```
[INFO] \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.1.5:compile
```

Platform:

```
Linux ariel 3.5.0-43-generic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 24 14:52:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How does `MetricTimeDataContext` implement / evaluate `equals()`? On what fields or in what circumstances? Is it a custom class or from a lib?

Comment: Also how does `MetricTimeDataContext` implement `Comparable.compareTo`? A `ConcurrentSkipListSet` may rely on a natural ordering that is consistent with equality (that is if `a.equals(b)` then `a.compareTo(b)==0` and vice versa -- are you sure this is the case?). The root cause of the problem is most certainly in equals/hashCode/compareTo somewhere.

Comment: @mbs, it is a custom impl. shouldn't the Assertions in the unit test suffice... is there a reason to see the impl ? i added a new assertion and that also passes. so line 4, does a compare and entry1 > entry2. line 5 does a equality check and proves not equal, line 6 does an inverse equality (what the doc is stating csls does. line 7 verifies hash codes are not equal

Comment: ok. thanks guys. I just added some more tests for comparison that exposed the flaw in comparison. will update the posting

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your equals is fine (As ConcurrentHashMap is fine) but compareTo doesn't match (as ConcurrentSkipListMap is a problem).  I would check in your test that compareTo and equals are consistent for the objects you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I added this update to my original post above minutes after posting since SO doesnt allow you to answer you own question for 8hr.

So I added 2 more tests at the very top:

```
Assert.assertEquals(-1, entry2 <=> entry1) // this returns 0 instead of -1
Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, entry2.equals(entry1))
```

**So my comparison algorithm was incorrect. @JasonC hit upon this about 15 mins after I posted this.**

Also the documentation is misleading since it clearly states that add depends on equals which it does not. The add depends on compareTo and in my case entry2.compareTo(entry1) which was returning 0 instead of -1.

Of course it is best practice to have equals match your compareTo logic.

So thanks to all that responded.